# How can users trustlessly verify ownership of RMRK NFTs

Tags: rmrk

On chains that implement an EVM, nfts that follow the ERC-721 standard can easily be queried by tokenID to find out the owner, what would be the RMRK equivalent?

Would users have to scan through every remark made on chain and filter out the particular NFT they are looking for, then step through, following the protocol spec to determine the owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truly verify it trustlessly, yes, you would have to consolidate all remarks ever made by using the [Consolidator](https://github.com/rmrk-team/rmrk-tools/blob/master/cli/consolidate.ts). You can fetch the remarks with the [fetcher](https://github.com/rmrk-team/rmrk-tools/blob/master/cli/fetch.ts).

We do provide [ready-made dumps](https://docs.rmrk.app/syncing) of remarks so you do not have to fetch them all, and can run the consolidator on those instead, this saves a few days. However, it does imply trust in the dumps.

Other than that there is no other way to verify ownership trustlessly on the "colored coins" implementation of RMRK (using remarks on Kusama or Statemine).

Answer (score 1):

For the on-chain RMRK protocol, it is indeed the case. However,

- RMRK has a new version on Moonriver
- Statemine's assets doesn't have this issue

Basically the initial implementation (as I understand) was pushing the chain itself into directions it didn't have pallets for (and no contracts existed), using tools at-hand. In this case remarks.

Expect chaos... I guess :)